# Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport completed

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is there a any way to know when a Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport command has finished importing? The command returns pretty much immediately, but i can't find a way to check when the import has actually completed into my existing database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546725.aspx) starts an import which is an async operation. If you want to check the status of an import you will need to store the import request in a variable. See below:

```
$importRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseImport -SqlConnectionContext $SqlCtx -StorageContainer $Container -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -BlobName $BlobName
```

After you store the request in a variable you can then use the [Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546734.aspx) cmdlet to track the status of the import. See below:

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -Request $importRequest
```

Hope this helps!